# How to update golang on codeanywhere.com with Ubuntu

Tags: go, codeanywhere

How to update golang on codeanywhere.com with Ubuntu 14.04?

The default container uses the version from Ubuntu repos, instead of golang PPA.

As of writing it's 1.6 and the newest version is 1.9.

Comment: a comment on a down-vote would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

(can't comment yet) Just an additional information, the steps in Paweł Prażak's answer work when you run on a Blank Container. If you run them on a Go predefined stack it won't update.

I also recommend to change the GOPATH value to your workspace, running

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

Then run `go env` to check if the values are correctly updated.

Thanks for the answer by the way, Paweł!

Comment: `$HOME/go` resolves to `"/home/cabox/go"` and it's the go default

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install the latest golang release in the container by using this script:

```
git clone https://github.com/udhos/update-golang
cd update-golang
sudo ./update-golang.sh
```

Full details: https://github.com/udhos/update-golang

Answer (score -1):

Create and new `Blank Container` with Ubuntu:
[image]

Connect to the container with SSH.

Follow the [instructions on the official wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu).

First install the `add-apt-repository` support:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
```

Now install the recent version of golang (refer to the wiki for up to date instructions):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gophers/archive
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang-1.9-go
```

Make sure to put the binary on `PATH`, e.g.:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/go-1.9/bin/go /usr/local/bin/go
```

Now the newer version should be available:

```
$ go version
go version go1.9.2 linux/amd64
```

Add `$GOPATH` pointing to the `workspace` and add `$GOPATH/bin` to `$PATH` in `~/.profile`:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.profile
export GOPATH="\$HOME/workspace"
export PATH="\$GOPATH/bin:\$PATH"
EOF
```

Apply the new `~/.profile`:

```
. ~/.profile
```

Also `make` is missing, if you need it:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```